# appendchlid() is replacing data column instead of appeding

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My aim is to display data table from Google sheet on my web app in a table.
Script is only displaying last `data column` from `dataArray`.
Could anyone please help, why this code is only able to append last data column and not all.

Code.gs

```js
function getTableDataTV(){
  
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById("").getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const data = ws.getRange (1,1,ws.getLastRow(), 9).getDisplayValues();
 
return data
```

HTML

```js
<html>
  <head>
   <script>
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableDataTV();
 });
 function generateTable(dataArray){
   var tabledb = document.getElementById("ptable");
   console.log(dataArray);
   dataArray.forEach(function(item, index){
     if(index == 0){
            var theaddb = document.createElement("thead");
            var rhead = document.createElement("tr");
            var th = document.createElement("th");
            console.log(dataArray[0].length);
              for(var i=0;i<(dataArray[0].length);i++){
                th.textContent = item[i];
                rhead.appendChild(th);
                }
                theaddb.appendChild(rhead);
                tabledb.appendChild(theaddb);
          }
          else if(index > 0)
          {
            var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
            var rbody = document.createElement("tr");
            var td = document.createElement("td");
              for(var i=0;i<(dataArray[0].length);i++){
                td.textContent = item[i];
                rbody.appendChild(td);
                }
                tbody.appendChild(rbody);
                tabledb.appendChild(tbody);
          }
   }); 
  }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="col s12">
    <table id = "ptable">
    </table>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

console.log(dataArray);

```js
​
0: Array(9) [ "DATE", "TITLE 1", "TITLE 2", … ]
1: Array(9) [ "2021-11-01", "3094392", "6338933", … ]
​2: Array(9) [ "2021-11-02", "3841183", "6731805", … ]
​3: Array(9) [ "2021-11-03", "5267740", "7713644", … ]
​4: Array(9) [ "2021-11-04", "3144660", "6177727", … ]
​5: Array(9) [ "2021-11-05", "3677444", "8649906", … ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue here is that you declared the td element once outside the for loop then keep changing and appending the same element.

try modify your code like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<(dataArray[0].length);i++){
   var td = document.createElement("td");
   td.textContent = item[I];
   rbody.appendChild(td);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about modifying `generateTable` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function generateTable(dataArray) {
  var tabledb = document.getElementById("ptable");
  var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  dataArray.forEach(function (item, index) {
    var len = item.length;
    if (index == 0) {
      var theaddb = document.createElement("thead");
      var rhead = document.createElement("tr");
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");
        th.textContent = item[i];
        rhead.appendChild(th);
      }
      theaddb.appendChild(rhead);
      tabledb.appendChild(theaddb);
    } else {
      var rbody = document.createElement("tr");
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.textContent = item[i];
        rbody.appendChild(td);
      }
      tbody.appendChild(rbody);
    }
  });
  tabledb.appendChild(tbody);
}
```

- `var th = document.createElement("th");` and `var td = document.createElement("td");` are included in the for loop.
- `tabledb.appendChild(tbody)` is moved to out side of the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much Tanaike. Now, its clear to me what I did wrong. Always appreciate your help.